# Creating structure of all tables from one database in other snowflake database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two db on one snowflake account. Database db1 with schema sch_a and db2 with sch_b. I would like to create all tables from db1, schema sch_a in db2, sch_b. How can I move all tables from one db to other db? I need just structure of the tables without data, so empty tables. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the GET_DDL or CREATE  … CLONE

```
-- THis will give you the DDL of all the objects in the schema
select get_ddl ('schema', 'source', true);

-- THis will copy the DB with the data
create database mytestdb_clone clone mytestdb;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Comment: In order to understand this, my source will be bd1  and I wil run this select on db2?

Comment: To get the DDL of all the objects you will run this in the source db1 and then you can execute the script in DB2

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have just one more questions. If I would like to move tables with data between databases? In order to copy or move tables from one db to anouther?

Comment: Hi , did you try Clone, may be that could work for you  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Comment: Yes I did. I'm using shared db but it's working. Thank you.